# How can I disable Hotwire / Turbo (the Turbolinks replacement) for all forms in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, turbolinks, turbo, hotwire

In Rails 7, Turbolinks is replaced by Hotwire / Turbo. This patches up web links so that they become AJAX-style requests just like Turbolinks did, but also patches up forms. On the whole, we found this broke swathes of our application.

- Forms that already had some kind of JS behaviour attached conflicted.
- Standard Rails error handling idioms - "set the `flash` and `render :new`/`render :edit`" - break, astonishingly; one must add `status: :unprocessable_entity` and cross fingers.
- If the controller handling a form submission redirects to a URL that includes a patch anchor (`...#foo`), Turbo strips it.

In the end, there's only so much `data: {turbo: false}` it makes sense to scatter all over your code base. Worse, we're using SimpleForm, so this becomes the even-more-cumbersome `html: {data: {turbo: false}}`.

Is there a way to _globally disable Turbo **just for forms** (ideally *all* forms, whatever their origin - just leave the `<form>` tag and everything inside it completely alone please) but leave the rest of its behaviour unchanged?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wish granted, although, undocumented. Available since [*turbo v7.2.0*](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/releases/tag/v7.2.0) *(turbo-rails v1.3.0)*.

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

Turbo.setFormMode("on" | "off" | "optin")
```

**`"on"`** - *default* - Turbo forms all the time. Use `data-turbo="false"` to disable turbo on individual forms.

**`"off"`** - No turbo forms ever. `data-turbo="true"` is ignored.

**`"optin"`** - No turbo forms unless you insist. Use `data-turbo="true"` to enable turbo on individual forms.

---

*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/pull/419*

Comment: Worrying that it's not documented, since it could be removed without warning, but it's very clear from the feature PR what was happening and there seemed a clear understanding of what was going on. So, good stuff! It's sort-of an "official" feature. Thanks.

Comment: WARNING on this: If you use "off", it disables ALL Turbo extensions, not just "data-turbo" for forms - it also disables things like using "data-turbo-method" on plain links. We found that out the hard way! The correct solution in that case is "optin".

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson that seems annoying. to clarify a bit, when using `data-turbo-method` (and some other turbo attributes), *Turbo* creates a form on the fly which is then submitted https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.3.0/src/observers/form_link_click_observer.ts#L33-L66 and "off" means no turbo forms ever, for any reason.

Comment: on the other hand, maybe that should be a bug, since the form still should happen and then be submitted as HTML and not TURBO_STREAM.

Comment: Does `Turbo.setFormMode('optin')` affect plain GET links that have `data: { turbo: true }` or `data: { turbo_method: :get }`? (I'm expecting a link to send a turbo request, and it is sending as `text/html` or `*/*`. I've also tried adding `format: :turbo_stream` to the link params, and adding `defaults: { format: :turbo_stream }` to the route. No dice, the controller does not process the request as turbo.)

Comment: @nimmolo it doesn't affect it. to send a turbo_stream request from a GET link or a GET form add `data: {turbo_stream: true}`

Answer (score 3):

I posted this Q&A on Stack Overflow as I couldn't find any other solutions out there. Clearly, there are numerous shortcomings and I would **much prefer to see a simple configuration flag for Turbo that would make it ignore forms - this would be an overwhelmingly preferable approach.**

I still don't have a full solution either way, because forms generated internally by Rails for e.g. a `link_to(...method: delete)` are still a problem, but I did work around some of it using some monkey patching.

On the one hand there are Rails forms:

- Apparently, a `data-turbo` attribute's value apples to that node *and all children* so one can wrap e.g. a Rails-generated 'dynamic' form from e.g. a `link_to(...method: delete)` in a DIV with that attribute set and, at least, work around those problems on a case-by-case basis - *though note, I'm having trouble making this work in some cases still*.
- If you have a lot of these, though, that's going to be intrusive and ugly, so it'd still be nice to have a way to have Turbo just ignore forms completely.

On the other hand there are SimpleForm forms:

- SimpleForm provides no way to globally configure data attributes that will be added to `form` elements that it constructs. Previous requests for this in GitHub issues have so far been explicitly refused.
- SimpleForm appears to provide no way to configure a wrapper that would go around the *form* as a whole, only custom wrappers for *inputs* within a form. So we can't easily just e.g. write a wrapper DIV as mentioned above.

I happened to be involved in a [gem called Hoodoo](https://www.rubygems.org/gems/hoodoo) that [provides monkey patching facilities](http://loyaltynz.github.io/hoodoo/guides_0850_monkey.html) that lets you write patch modules which are more like subclasses - `super` is available to call up to the patched implementation - and, further, patches can be enabled or disabled dynamically and easily. Hoodoo is actually a Rack application service framework, so this is something of a sledgehammer - I always intended to one day extract this into its own gem, but at the time of writing, I have not got around to it (and several years have gone by) - but we can `require` just the part we need and ignore the rest.

Here, I patch SimpleForm's builder methods. These just call Rails' form helpers under the hood, so I might have a go at patching lower down in Rails instead, but anyway, the following worked.

In your `Gemfile`, declare the Hoodoo dependency but don't load all of its component parts as you won't want most of them.

```rb
# Hoodoo's monkey patch module is useful sometimes:
# https://rubygems.org/gems/hoodoo
#
# MUST use 'require: false' so that the Rack components of Hoodoo middleware
# do not get activated; this is a Rails app, not a Hoodoo service!
#
gem 'hoodoo', '~> 2.12', require: false
```

...then write something like `config/initializers/simple_form_monkey_patch.rb` which looks something like this:

```rb
require 'hoodoo/monkey'

module SimpleFormMonkey
  module InstanceExtensions
    def simple_form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
      modified_options = {html: {data: {turbo: false}}}
      modified_options.deep_merge!(options)

      super(record, modified_options, &block)
    end
  end
end

Hoodoo::Monkey.register(
  extension_module: SimpleFormMonkey,
  target_unit:      SimpleForm::ActionViewExtensions::FormHelper
)

Hoodoo::Monkey.enable(
  extension_module: SimpleFormMonkey
)
```

...that'll do it. This has some risk as we're patching things which are - in terms of the module name & nesting - technically private to SimpleForm, but the method signature itself is at least public. You could patch `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` with an override for `form_for` instead, if you wanted to go lower level and patch an API that's been stable for a very long time. The code would be almost identical as the method signatures are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I used Javascript to solve this problem:

```
  document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function (el) {
    el.dataset.turbo = false
  })
```

No more flaky system tests due to randomly missing flash messages/alerts after form submissions and Devise also works perfectly again.

Comment: How do you make sure that this runs *after* Turbo itself has already hooked into forms?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `turbo drive` by adding these lines to your `application.js`:

```js
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

More info: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms

Comment: That turns off Turbo globally. The question was about turning off Turbo for just forms, since it causes many problems there.

My own self-answered response gives a robust low-level way to do that for SimpleForm, while @kamilpogo gives a JavaScript-based solution that uses fewer lines of code but makes assumptions about order of execution that might not always work out in practice - the JS patch would always have to run somehow *before* Turbo scanned the document.

Answer (score 0):

@kamilpogo your solution worked like a charm! ty!!! currently learning and following [this GoRails tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sT_3Trmtw0&list=PLm8ctt9NhMNV75T9WYIrA6m9I_uw7vS56&t=30s) before i ran into some turbo trouble trying to render "Thanks!" for anyone else out there.

basically, i added the javascript to in /layouts/application.html.erb like below:

```
<script>    
    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function (el) {    
                el.dataset.turbo = false    
    })    
</script>    
<script src="js-bootstrap"></script>    
  </body>    
</html>
```

UPDATE: comments in the videos have a different work around by setting turbo to 'false' and local to 'true' inside the form:

```
form_with model: @user, url: sign_up_path, local: true, data: { turbo:false } do |form|
```